# Python Graphql Django Server Mutation info.context.files return empty list without file

Tags: python, django, graphql

On my front-end the file is being send to the server when I tried to access **kwargs dictionary I can see the of the file being received in the server but when I tried to access the file by info.context.FILES its sending an empty list which does have any file my code are here:

```
class CreateAgency(graphene.Mutation):
id = graphene.UUID()
authorName = graphene.String()
authorEmail = graphene.String()
authorPhone = graphene.Int()
agencyName = graphene.String()
agencyAddress = graphene.String()
thefile = Upload()  #graphene.String()
agencyLandlineNumber = graphene.Int()
agencyEmail = graphene.String()
agencyWebsite = graphene.String()
userId = graphene.UUID()

class Arguments:
    authorName = graphene.String()
    authorEmail = graphene.String()
    authorPhone = graphene.Int()
    agencyName = graphene.String()
    agencyAddress = graphene.String()
    thefile = Upload()  #graphene.String()
    agencyLandlineNumber = graphene.Int()
    agencyEmail = graphene.String()
    agencyWebsite = graphene.String()
    userId = graphene.UUID()

#@classmethod
@staticmethod
def mutate(self,  info, **kwargs):    #self, file, info, **kwargs
    authorName = kwargs.get('authorName')
    authorEmail = kwargs.get('authorEmail')
    authorPhone = kwargs.get('authorPhone')
    agencyName = kwargs.get('agencyName')
    agencyAddress = kwargs.get('agencyAddress')
    thisfinal =  kwargs.get('thefile')  #file string
    #files = info.context.FILES.get(file)
    #files = kwargs.context.FILES['thefile']
    agencyLandlineNumber = kwargs.get('agencyLandlineNumber')
    agencyEmail = kwargs.get('agencyEmail')
    agencyWebsite = kwargs.get('agencyWebsite')
    userId = kwargs.get('userId')

    print(type(thisfinal))

    #print(info.context.FILES['thefile'])
    #print(info.context.FILES)
    print(kwargs)
    #print(context)
    print(info.context.FILES.getlist('thefile'))
    print(info.context.FILES)

    if info.context.FILES and info.context.method == 'POST':
        getFile = info.context.FILES['thefile']
        print("#######################")
        print(info.context.FILES)
        print(kwargs)
        print(self)
        #print(context)
        print(getFile)

    print("#######################")
    #print(files)
    #print(thisfinal)
    print("#######################")
    print(agencyName)
    print("#######################")

    actionCreate = realEstateAgencies(
        authorName = authorName,
        authorEmail = authorEmail,
        authorPhone = authorPhone,
        agencyName = agencyName,
        agencyAddress = agencyAddress,
        angencyLogo =   thisfinal,
        agencyLandlineNumber = agencyLandlineNumber,
        agencyEmail = agencyEmail,
        agencyWebsite = agencyWebsite,
        #userId = userId
    )
    actionCreate.save()

    return CreateAgency(
        id = actionCreate.id
    )

class AgencyCreateMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    createagency = CreateAgency.Field()
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Where did you put your files? I don't even know where to put them at.